# Update Array inside a Nested Array Object in Firestore Document

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Document Data with the following structure as shown below. I want to update a particular object inside "arrayInsideArray" without changing the index of other objects in it. For instance, if I want to update object with "name = item1" with an object with "name = item4",
it should just update the object of "name = item1" with the object of "name = item4" without changing the position of other objects inside "arrayInsideArray". I am a beginner in NodeJs and Typescript and I would like someone to help me out with this.

```
{
  array: [
          {
            order: 1,
            arrayInsideArray: 
              [ {
                  id: 1,
                  name = item1,
                  ...
                  ...
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  name = item2,
                  ...
                  ...
                },
                {
                  ...
                  ...
                }
              ]
          },
          {
           order: 2,
            arrayInsideArray: 
              [ {
                  id: 3,
                  name = item3,
                  ...
                  ...
                },
                {
                  ...
                  ...
                }
              ]
          },
          {
            ...
            ...
          }
        ]
          ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with a `map` operator.

If the item is not the one you are looking for, just return it as it is. Otherwise, perform the change.
This will ensure the same order.

Example replacing the whole item:

```js
function updateInternalArray(searchedOrder: number, searchedId: number, newItem: any) {
        return myData.array.map((item) => {
           return item.order ===  searchedOrder
                ? { // this is the parent item you want to look at
                  ...item, 
                  arrayInsideArray: item.arrayInsideArray.map((internalItem) => {
                        return internalItem.id === searchItem
                             ? newItem // this is the internal item you want to update
                             : internalItem; // this is another internal item, that you want to keep it untouched
                  })
                }
                : item; // this a parent item that you want to keep it as it is
        })
    }
```

Be careful to not override the id, for example.

Example updating the item:

```js
function updateInternalArray(searchedOrder: number, searchedId: number, newItem: any) {
        return myData.array.map((item) => {
           return item.order ===  searchedOrder
                ? { // this is the parent item you want to look at
                  ...item, 
                  arrayInsideArray: item.arrayInsideArray.map((internalItem) => {
                        return internalItem.id === searchItem
                             ? {...internalItem, ...newItem} // this is the internal item you want to update
                             : internalItem; // this is another internal item, that you want to keep it untouched
                  })
                }
                : item; // this a parent item that you want to keep it as it is
        })
    }
```

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could help me out with a sample code

Comment: Sorry, just updated.
The idea, as explained, is that the map will be applied to each item in the array. In each iteration, you check if the current item is the one you want to update, otherwise, you simply the current item without any modifications.

In the example above, I just applied the same concept, but in the two arrays (searching for order number and id)

Comment: I will try out the above logic and get back to you. Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: I understood the code but the thing is i want to completely update the internalItem and not just the name of it.

Comment: I have updated the code. This will update the whole thing, so be careful not to lose the id of it.
Otherwise, instead of completely replacing it, you can use the spreading operator.

I have updated the code to reflect the two options